# How can i store a BLOB image into a temporary file?

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I am currently storing images into a database, i can display them on a webpage just fine using the following code:

```
<?php 
$type = "image/png"; //or the actual mime type of the file
$base64blob = base64_encode($portal['image']); //encode to base64
$datauri = "data:$type;base64,$base64blob";
?>
```

The problem is that i need to save it as a temporary file so that it can be used in the following code using phpspreadsheet where setpath line would be the temporary file:

```
$drawing = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing();
$drawing->setName('Logo');
$drawing->setDescription('Logo');
$drawing->setPath('./images/officelogo.jpg');
$drawing->setHeight(36);
```

Is there any way to do this as i am a novice, Thanks

Comment: You want the temp file to be `./images/officelogo.jpg`?

Comment: temp file can be anything, i just need to be able to store the blob as a temp file and then load it in 
    $drawing->setPath('./images/officelogo.jpg');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ext = explode("/",$type);
$filename = './images/'.uniqid(rand(), true) . '.'.$ext[1];
file_put_contents($filename,$portal['image']);
$drawing->setPath($filename);
// make Spreadsheet
unlink($filename);
```